# Excel VBA - filter rows within dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

On Excel spreadsheet I want to filter out rows which have TRUE in column J. 
Running line below works, but only for that specific range - A5:J38:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$J$38").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="FALSE"
```

Need for the range to adjust automatically to include rows which have a result in formula displayed in column J (it's either TRUE or FALSE). Code below gives "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="FALSE"
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter  Field:=10, Criteria1:="FALSE"`

Comment: I was afraid that might not work, because my first row, where my filters are, is row 5, and I have other things, which I don't want filtered, in first five rows, but I tried and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to make a small edit:

```
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:J" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="FALSE"
End With
```