# varying rows auto-filter

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the original post so I think I have to ask here...
[Excel VBA - filter rows within dynamic range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267892/excel-vba-filter-rows-within-dynamic-range) I'm trying to change my VBA to filter rows with dynamic ranges. My code is below but I'm not sure what to change it to?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$18791").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Custom", "Health & Welfare", "Insurance", "Retirement & Savings"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
```

I see from the other post the reply has

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter  Field:=10, Criteria1:="FALSE"
```

Would my code be;

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter  Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Custom", "Health & Welfare", "Insurance", "Retirement & Savings"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
```

My main question is when ".UsedRange" is used, do I have to set the range first? Could someone provide me with the edits I need if needed? In short, I'm trying to filter column K by the criteria but it doesn't end in row 18791 each week so I'm trying to make sure my code grabs the varying data each week.

Comment: No, you don't have to set `UsedRange`. Another option is to [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: So by putting UsedRange, it's just selecting all rows used in the file? If so, is my updated code there correct?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange